# Why are my textures being applied to objects that aren’t selected?

Tags: texturing, objects

I’m trying to add an image texture on a certain object, but when I connect the image texture node to the principled shaded node, other objects in my scene are having the texture being applied to them as well. I made sure my object was UV unwrapped, I tried separating the object by selection, and I just can’t seem to figure out what’s causing this to happen. It’s almost like Blender thinks those objects are part of the same node group. I’m rather new to Blender, so I’m not sure if this is a simple fix or not. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think all the objects have the same material, if yu add an object to the scene and instead of assigning new material sharing same material will result in this case 
Or 
Duplicating objects with ctrl + d instead of shift + d will also cause the same thing.

Comment: Is there anyway to remedy this? Or will I have to remake all of my objects?

Comment: Try to apply new materials for other objects.